# Not iterating through JSON result rows

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to simply print out the data for each row of a JSON result
The path structure is correct but its only doing the data for row 1

Here is the code

```
$row = $obj->response->result->Accounts->row;
foreach($row as $r) 
{
print($r->FL[0]->content).',';
print($r->FL[1]->content).',';
print($r->FL[2]->content).',';
print($r->FL[3]->content).',';
print($r->FL[4]->content).',';
print($r->FL[5]->content).',';
print($r->FL[6]->content).',';
}
```

The JSON result 
** Because people havent been reading the question properly here is the ENTIRE JSON result

```
    {
  "response": {
    "result": {
      "Accounts": {
        "row": [
          {
            "no": "1",
            "FL": [
              {
                "val": "ACCOUNTID",
                "content": "3508588000000259001"
              },
              {
                "val": "SMOWNERID",
                "content": "3508588000000176021"
              },
              {
                "val": "Account Owner",
                "content": "Chris Yates"
              },
              {
                "val": "Rating",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Account Name",
                "content": "Test Co"
              },
              {
                "val": "Phone",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Account Site",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Fax",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "PARENTACCOUNTID",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Parent Account",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Website",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Account Number",
                "content": "0"
              },
              {
                "val": "Ticker Symbol",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Account Type",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Ownership",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Industry",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Employees",
                "content": "0"
              },
              {
                "val": "Annual Revenue",
                "content": "129000"
              },
              {
                "val": "SIC Code",
                "content": "0"
              },
              {
                "val": "SMCREATORID",
                "content": "3508588000000176021"
              },
              {
                "val": "Created By",
                "content": "Chris Yates"
              },
              {
                "val": "MODIFIEDBY",
                "content": "3508588000000176021"
              },
              {
                "val": "Modified By",
                "content": "Chris Yates"
              },
              {
                "val": "Created Time",
                "content": "2018-09-20 09:56:30"
              },
              {
                "val": "Modified Time",
                "content": "2018-09-20 12:39:56"
              },
              {
                "val": "Billing Street",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Shipping Street",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Billing City",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Shipping City",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Billing State",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Shipping State",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Billing Code",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Shipping Code",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Billing Country",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Shipping Country",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Description",
                "content": "null"
              },
              {
                "val": "Last Activity Time",
                "content": "2018-09-20 12:39:56"
              },
              {
                "val": "Tag",
                "content": "null"
              }
            ]
          },
```

There is the entire JSON result - there are over 400 rows

Comment: Row mean one row not data collection. Try use rows.

Comment: Thats the path 
so to get the data from item number 1 it would be 
$obj->response->result->Accounts->row->FL[0]->content;

Comment: it is all should be `$r->FL[0]->content` without incremented indexes

Comment: @hassan That would only display the data from the 1st item 
I want to display the data from each item I have specified and iterate through all rows ( there are over 400 not just the 1 you can see above )
Also to get the same item content FL[0] on the second row it would be $r[1]->FL[0]->content

Comment: Whoever downvoted care to explain why ?
So far people haven't been reading the question properly

Comment: Why is the row json property has its curly bracket closed before the data with no 2?

Comment: @ChrisYates can you post the full json? or at least add more json chunks

Comment: @JerdineSabio I cut it down do you could see there are multiple rows rather than paste the entire structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop again in FL;

```
foreach($row as $r) 
{
    foreach($r->FL as $data)
    print($data->content).',';
}
```

To stop outputting commas upon reaching a certain number;

```
foreach($row as $r) 
{
    $data_count = count($r->FL);
    $counter = 0;

    foreach($r->FL as $data)
    {
        if($data_count < $counter)
        {
           print($data->content).',';
        }
        else
        {
           print($data->content);
        }

        $counter++;
    }

}
```

Display in new line (html);

```
foreach($row as $r) 
{
    foreach($r->FL as $data)
    print($data->content).'<br>';
}
```

Display in new line (excel);

What I've noticed was you have to literally output your echo in a new line.
An excel file table has this data

```
|1|2|3|4|5|
|1|2|3|4|5|
```

and its csv file equivalent is

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Perfect !
I tried something similar ( before I pasted my code but couldnt get it working )
Will accept answer soon as it lets me .. cheers

Comment: How am I able to get each row being displayed on a new line ?

Comment: You could replace the ',' with '<br>'. Thanks too, good luck with the project!

Comment: am using the , to create a simple csv file hence the need for a new line for each row

Comment: Ah, you could try print($data->content).'\n';

Comment: nope that just added \n after each item being echo'd not after each row

Comment: That works.. thanks for your help ,
one quick question .. is there any way to stop it adding a , to the end of the last item

Comment: Np, I added another set of code for that; use count,++, and if.